# citation, tables and equation exceed page width in beamer

Tags: latex, beamer

I am using Latex for the first time and I am preparing a slide using 'beamer'. What happening is that some of my citations, tables and long equations are exceeding beyond the text width, though it wasn't the problem when the document class was 'article'. My tables aren't long, as one of them has only 3 rows and 6 columns.

The latex codes are

```
    \documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\definecolor{BlueGreen}{cmyk}{0.85,0,0.33,0}
\colorlet{beamer@blendedblue}{BlueGreen!120}}

\usepackage{booktabs} 

\usepackage{caption}


\hypersetup{pdfnewwindow}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{postit}{bg=violet!110}
\usepackage{ragged2e}   %new code

\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying} 



\usepackage{textpos}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame} \frametitle{\textbf{{\Large Objective}}}
    \begin{itemize}
        \justifying
            \item This package gives you easy access to the Lorem Ipsum dummy text; an option is available to separate the paragraphs of the dummy text. This text \cite{kumar2015method}.
        
        \item The long equation is: 
        \begin{equation} 
        A(\theta,\alpha) = \dfrac{ A*{-(\alpha*A)}\beta*{(\delta-1)} \left(A* \hspace{1mm}\hspace{1mm}C^{-A Z_{H}} \hspace{1mm}C^{-C^{-A *Z_{H}}} \prod_{i=1}^{m-1} \left( \dfrac{ A \hspace{1mm}C^{-A* Z_{u(i)}} C^{-C^{-A* Z_{u(i)}}}}{1- \frac{1}{C-1} (C^{1-C^{-A  Z_{u(i)}}}-1)}\right) \right) }{ \int_{0}^{\infty} C^{-(\alpha *A)}(A^{(\beta-1)} \left( A* \hspace{1mm}\hspace{1mm}C^{-A Z_{H}} \hspace{1mm}C^{-C^{-A Z_{H}}} \prod_{i=1}^{B-1} \left(\dfrac{ A \hspace{1mm}C^{-A Z_{u(i)}} C^{-C^{-A* Z_{u(i)}}}}{1- \frac{1}{C-1} (C^{1-C^{-A* Z_{u(i)}}}-1)}\right) \right) A}  .
        \end{equation}                          
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\bibliography{ref}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\end{document}
```

And the contents of the .bib file is:

```
@article{kumar2015method,
    title={This is the title of the article},
    author={Kumar, Dinesh and others},
    journal={This is Journal},
    volume={2},
    number={3},
    pages={150-180},
    year={2015}
}
```

Comment: The problem of tables is fixed. Thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38177/including-large-tables-in-a-beamer-frame?newreg=b0607cb657404f49970c23a512e5add7

Comment: Can you make a [mre] with your remaining problems?

Comment: And DON"T use the `\resizebox` solution from the thread you linked to, that's a terrible idea

Comment: I have added the codes in the question. Too many commands might not be needed, but as Latex is new to me, I kept these commands. And please suggest alternate to \resizebox.

Comment: How to best squeeze the table into your slide will depend on the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you use the `plainnat` bib style, you should also load the natbib package. This will automatically allow line breaks

[image]

- you don't need the `caption` package, beamer provides it's own mechanism  to customise captions
- you must place the `bibliography` inside a frame
- for the very large equation, I would suggest to replace the fraction with `(...) \times (...)^{-1}`, this way you can split it over multiple lines. In addition you'll probably want to use a smaller font size and maybe remove all the manual spaces.

---

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\definecolor{BlueGreen}{cmyk}{0.85,0,0.33,0}
\makeatletter
\colorlet{beamer@blendedblue}{BlueGreen!120}
\makeatother
}

\usepackage{booktabs} 
%\usepackage{caption}


\hypersetup{pdfnewwindow}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{postit}{bg=violet!110}
\usepackage{ragged2e}   %new code

\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying} 


\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{textpos}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} \frametitle{\textbf{{\Large Objective}}}
    \begin{itemize}
        \justifying
            \item This package gives you easy access to the Lorem Ipsum dummy text; an option is available to separate the paragraphs of the dummy text. This text \cite{kumar2015method}.
        
        \item The long equation is:                        
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\bibliography{ref}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I copied these commands in my original presentation (which is quite lengthy) I got an error 'Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}' and the line where  \captionof{figure}{PDF  of the distribution} is highlighted. I have used \minipage to place images side by side.

Comment: @rgt If you want to use `\captionof`, you'll need the caption package. However you could simply use beamer columns to place two figure environments side by side.

Comment: Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, after using \usepackage{caption} I got the output.